# Inserting value from one table into another

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys

Im trying to insert a value once its created from one table into another I have two databases 'mem' and 'location'

I want to add the primary key 'id' from the mem table and insert it into a column 'user_id' in the location table.

I have a sql query in my registration form page that auto increments the 'id' in the mem table yet does not seem to add the same value into the user_id in the location table,

```
$id = mysql_insert_id(); mysql_query("INSERT INTO location (user_id) 
            VALUES (SELECT id FROM mem)");
```

Can someone please help!

Answer (score 1):

The proper query is:

```
INSERT INTO location (user_id) SELECT id FROM mem
```

However, this query will actually insert *all* id values from 'mem' into 'location'.  To add the most recent id, you will want to use

```
INSERT INTO location (user_id) VALUES ($id)
```